# How to reset a GTK Image?

Tags: c, gtk

im using c to create a GUI with GTK 3 and i face a problem , i want that a callback fonction (named "draw") print an image every time a button is pressed . The problem is that the images doesnt refresh , it add another image down the first and let the first visible . I try to use gtk_image_clear and gtk_image_set but the problem still exist , any help ?

The callback prototype

```
g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(pDrawBtn), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(Draw),(GtkWidget*) pDiceDrawBox);
```

The "Draw" Function

```
#include <gtk/gtk.>

void Draw(GtkWidget *pDrawBtn, GtkWidget *Box)
{

GtkWidget *pImage;
GtkWidget *pCheck;
int face = 0;

pCheck = gtk_container_get_children(GTK_CONTAINER(Box));

pImage = gtk_image_new_from_file("img/de/de1.png");

if (pCheck != NULL)
{
    gtk_image_clear(GTK_IMAGE(pImage));
}

srand(time(NULL));
face = (rand() % (6 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
switch (face)
{
    case 1:
        gtk_image_set_from_file(GTK_IMAGE(pImage), "img/de/de1.png");
    break;
    case 2:
        gtk_image_set_from_file(GTK_IMAGE(pImage), "img/de/de2.png");
    break;
    case 3:
        gtk_image_set_from_file(GTK_IMAGE(pImage), "img/de/de3.png");
    break;
    case 4:
        gtk_image_set_from_file(GTK_IMAGE(pImage), "img/de/de4.png");
    break;
    case 5:
        gtk_image_set_from_file(GTK_IMAGE(pImage), "img/de/de5.png");
    break;
    case 6:
        gtk_image_set_from_file(GTK_IMAGE(pImage), "img/de/de6.png");
    break;
}

gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(Box), pImage, TRUE, TRUE, 0);

gtk_widget_show_all(Box);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're unconditionally calling `gtk_box_pack_start(Box, pImage ..)` on your callback, so GTK does as it's asked everytime that function is called: it adds the Image widget (again) to the box. You should add the image only once, either by making sure that function is called on the first time the callback gets executed, or by adding it to the box beforehand.

Note also that the following is incorrect:

```
GtkWidget *pCheck;
//...
pCheck = gtk_container_get_children(GTK_CONTAINER(Box));
```

`gtk_container_get_children()` returns a `GList*`, not the element itself. So depending on what you actually want, you should either change the type of `pCheck`, or make sure you first extract it from the returned list.